# python error ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found. File "psycopg2\_psycopg.pyc", line 10, in __load

Tags: python, py2exe, packaging, importerror

I packaged a Windows application developped in python. For the setup, no problem. When launching it up on my PC (let's say PC1), no problem. But when trying to launch it on another PC (let's say PC2), an error message shows up indicating to read the MYAPPLICATION.exe.log file. There s 1 error (only 1), here are the lines of the log :

> File "MYAPPLICATION.pyc", line 9, in
>
> File "psycopg2__init__.pyc", line 50, in
>
> File "psycopg2_psycopg.pyc", line 12, in
>
> File "psycopg2_psycopg.pyc", line 10, in __load
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be
>   found.

Indications about my way of packaging :

- i used the command "setup.py py2exe --includes sip" (with the proper
  setup.py file) then InnoSetupCompiler.
- I embedded both folders 'dist' and 'build'. I even copied the
  psycopg2 folder from site-packages to 'dist' (as well as mpl-data for
  matplotlib b.t.w. for which one i have no problem) before packaging
  with InnoSetup, so that i'm sure the module psycopg2 is well present 
  on the PC2. But when I try to run it on the PC2 which occurs the
  error. Indications about PC2 : it has the python modules already
  installed on. (including the last version of psycog2)

So why does the psycog2 module import fails here ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"There are 2 DLLs that are required by pyscopg.pyd (secur32.dll & shfolder.dll) that are OS dependent."  Removing them should do the trick.  I got this solution from here: http://psycopg.initd.narkive.com/FX7WIxE6/import-error-using-psycopg2-with-py2exe